# How do I display text in a grid-like structure in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame and currently I'm working on creating a memory game where the computer displays boxes at random positions for like a second and then the user has to click on where he/she thinks those boxes are. It's kind of like [this game](http://www.lumosity.com/brain-games/memory-games/memory-matrix):

[image: screenshot]

However I'm not really sure how to make the computer display the boxes with like a letter or symbol e.g. 'T' or '%'. (I've already made the grid). 
Could anyone please help? It would be really appreciated.

```
import pygame
size=[500,500]
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# Colours
LIME = (0,255,0) 
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
PINK = (255,102,178)
SALMON = (255,192,203)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
LIGHT_PINK = (255, 181, 197)
SKY_BLUE = (176, 226, 255)
screen.fill(BLACK)

# Width and Height of game box
width=50
height=50

# Margin between each cell
margin = 5

# Create a 2 dimensional array. A two dimesional
# array is simply a list of lists.
grid=[]
for row in range(20):
    # Add an empty array that will hold each cell
    # in this row
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(20):
        grid[row].append(0) # Append a cell

# Set row 1, cell 5 to one. (Remember rows and
# column numbers start at zero.)
grid[1][5] = 1  

# Set title of screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Spatial Recall")

#Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done=False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while done==False:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done=True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
      if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        # User clicks the mouse. Get the position
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        # Change the x/y screen coordinates to grid coordinates
        column=pos[0] // (width+margin)
        row=pos[1] // (height+margin)
        # Sete t hat location to zero
        grid[row][column]=1
        print("Click ",pos,"Grid coordinates: ",row,column)


# Draw the grid
for row in range(10):
    for column in range(10):
        color = LIGHT_PINK
        if grid[row][column] == 1:
            color = RED
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,[(margin+width)*column+margin,(margin+height)*row+margin,width,height])

# Limit to 20 frames per second
clock.tick(20)

# Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit ()
```

Comment: I can't see that page, it seems to be behind a paywall. Could you provide a screenshot instead?

Answer (score 2):

In order to display text, you have to go through a series of steps.  First you will want to get a font by using the command `pygame.font.Font(font name, size).  For example:

```
arialfont=pygame.font.Font('arial', 12)
```

All available fonts can be gotten from the command `pygame.font.get_fonts()`.  Remember to initialize pygame (`pygame.init()`) before any of this.

Next, you will have to use the `Font.render(text, antialias, color, background=None)`.  For example:

```
text=arialfont.render('Hello World!', True, (0, 0, 0))
```

This will return a surface.  You can use it just like you would any other surface.  Use `text.get_rect()` to get its rect, then reposition the rect to put it where you want it to be, and blit it to the window.  If you don't know anything about surface objects, just ask me.

Here is a working code.

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()#never forget this line
window=pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
font=pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 40)
text=font.render('@', True, (0, 0, 0))
rect=text.get_rect()
window.fill((255, 255, 255))
window.blit(text, rect)
pygame.display.update()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, but you're right I've never been taught anything about Surface objects......

Comment: @nnekymoe No problem. A surface object is basically a stored picture withing the program.  It can be drawn onto other surfaces, or blitted, or can be drawn on with `pygame.draw`.  An example of a surface object is the screen, which may help you understand them.  In order to blit a surface object, you have to have a rectangle or rect, which you might know about.  To get a surface's rect use `surface.get_rect()`. I'll continue this in another comment.  I'm running out of characters.

Comment: @nnekymoe So, when you make a rect using the `get_rect()` function, it will put it in the upper left corner of the screen.  To change that, change its attributes such as left, right, top, bottom, centerx, centery, center, topleft, bottomleft, topright, and bottomright.  For example: `rect.bottom=430` or `rect.bottomleft=(0, 300)`.  To blit the surface object to the screen, or any other surface, use `screen.blit(surface, rect)`.  If you don't understand anything, I'm happy to help.

Comment: @PgameNerd Thanks again for the response. I tried blitting the object (this symbol: @) to the screen but it didn't give me anything. I've also tried going on the pygame website but that didn't help either. Is there something I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @nnekymoe I edited my answer to include a working code for blitting an `@` to a window.  See if you can figure out the problem yourself.  Otherwise, give me the code.